# flexbox columns with resizable image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a flexbox layout with a resizable image (with link) in the middle flex item. The image flex item should be scalable according to the browser window, and the other items as big as their content, but fixed height.

I want the image centered in both directions and having about 95% as max-height and max-width, so that is shrinks when the browser window gets smaller.

html:

```
<div id="flexbox">
    <div id="flex-1">1</div>
    <div id="flex-2">2</div>
    <div id="flex-3">
        <div id="zoom">
            <a href="http://xy.de">
                <img src="http://250kb.de/u/140905/j/lCdCSjetSUXb.jpg" alt="x" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="flex-4">4</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#flexbox { 
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
#flex-1{
    border:1px solid lightblue;
}
#flex-2{
    border:1px solid lime;
}
#flex-3 {
    border:1px solid yellow;
    flex:1;
    justify-content:center;
}
#flex-4 {
    border:1px solid pink;
}
#zoom{
    background:white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#zoom a{
    height:90%; 
}
#zoom img{
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/haheute/67py8zez/4/

How can I get the max-height and max-width right in firefox and chromium and how can I center the link with image in both directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mfwr0fcm/.

HTML:

```
<div id="flexbox">
    <div id="flex-1">1</div>
    <div id="flex-2">2</div>
    <div id="flex-3">
        <a href = "#"><img src="http://250kb.de/u/140905/j/lCdCSjetSUXb.jpg" alt="x" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="flex-4">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body, #flexbox {
    height:100%;
}

#flexbox { 
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background:red;
}

#flexbox > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#flex-3 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#flex-3 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 95%;
    max-height: 95%;
}
```